# Application not found on Android TV

Tags: google-play, android-tv

I have an app created for Android TV but I cannot discover it on Nexus Player when I try to search for it in Google Play Store. The application has been approved for distribution on Android TV but still not discoverable.

Any ideas what could be wrong with manifest/distribution options that causes the app to be filtered out on Nexus Player devices?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you mention that the TV supports LEANBACK:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.LEANBACK"
    android:required="true" />
```

And that the app does not require a touchscreen:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN"
    android:required="false" />
```

Without those manifest tags the Play Store may not show your app